# Retina iPad Specific CSS

Tags: ipad, css, media-queries, retina-display

I'm designing a responsive site that will look different on mobile devices.  I have three separate media queries in my css plus a query for retina display(s).

```
/** 768PX IPAD PORTRAIT **/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

/** 480PX IPHONE LANDSCAPE **/
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {}

/** 320PX PORTRAIT **/
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {}

/**  RETINA IMAGES **/
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

When iPad is in portrait mode, it will get the mobile version, but when it's in landscape mode it will get the regular version of the site.

My problem is this, now with the "new iPad" and retina display, certain retina images are not aligned properly for the landscape retina iPad version. The global retina css is overruling the regular css and it's supposed to I guess.

For example, in the mobile version, I have an background image centred on the screen, but on the regular site, it's left aligned.

Anyone know of a way to target only retina images for iPad only in CSS?

Thanks

Edit: This is what I was playing around with but it doesn't seem to work:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

Comment: The new iPad is 2048-by-1536... try that and the pixel-ratio: 2

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried it, nope, still doesn't work. @media screen and (min-device-width : 1536px) and (max-device-width : 2048px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}

Comment: Did you see my answer, and you're using an actual iPad3, right?

Comment: @user127181 Please add some code and description to your answer so that all can get it. Also I am having same issue currently. Please help!

Comment: need more effective answers here answers not working properly

Answer (score 13):

Figured it out.

I had my iPad Retina query below all other queries but they needed to be above the other queries starting from largest to smallest.

Comment: You should accept your answer as the correct answer and put the correct code you used so there's always a reference from your initial question to the correct answer with the proper code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```css
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1536px)
  and (max-device-width: 2048px)
  and (orientation : landscape)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      // Retina iPad specific CSS
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes I did see your answer but it doesn't work.  I'm only using the iOS simulator however.  All my other media queries work fine using the simulator however.  I'm stumped.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work on my ipad Retina.  it ignores it every time.  If I change it to @media screen and (max-width: 960px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) that works.  I have tripled checked to make sure my ipad is, in fact, an iPad retina (and I didn't get scammed) and the model number comes back as a legit iPad Retina.  Thoughts?

Comment: @MatthewLee Hmmm, my best guess right now would be that it has to do with max-width vs. max-device-width. Are you using an iPad 3 or 4?

Comment: Ipad 3.  Odd thing is I can't get your query to work on my actual iPad or on the iOS Simulator, but setting max-width to 960px works on both.  Your settings make sense to me.  Is there a good source for reading up on CSS queries that you can point me to?  Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewLee Sure, check out http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries and I know I've seen lots of good stuff on http://css-tricks.com/

Comment: this doesn't seem like a good idea - you're detecting an ipad '3' here and not a high resolution display. considering the OP eventually realized his problem was the order of queries this probably isn't a good general solution

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved using:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px), only screen and (max-device-width: 960px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)
```

For meta viewport I use:

```
content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1"
```

I don't know if this is a perfect solution, but it works.