# CSS Media Queries on iPad 3 (or the new iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, css, media-queries, ipad-3

Is there going to be any difference in applying the CSS Media Queries for detecting the iPad 3 or the new iPad?

Also the iPad 1 and iPad 2 returned device-width as 768px in both orientations. So is that the same on iPad 3 as well ?

Comment: We figured it out in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780189/retina-ipad-specific-css/9793715#9793715

Comment: Yes, even the answer below is helpful..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Media Queries for the new iPad (or iPad 3) remains almost the same.
So if you check for min-device-width as 768px, it would still work for the new iPad. However, to give a more specific query, you can check for device-width between 1536 px and 2048 px.

There is a very good tutorial on using CSS Media Queries at
http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/designmobileweb/id486198804?mt=8

Answer (score 7):

The new iPad reports the [same device-width](http://www.matchadesign.com/blog/thoughts-on-media-queries-and-the-ipad-3/) as the first and second iPads (768).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is.

If you're worried about the impact of the further increase in pixel resolution of the new Retina display, then add the following to your page's head element:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

See this article with very useful information on detecting the viewport dimensions:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3889591/Detect-and-Set-the-iPhone--iPads-Viewport-Orientation-Using-JavaScript-CSS-and-Meta-Tags.htm