# iPad 3 loading smartphone images

Tags: html, css, ipad

I'm using the following media query to load retina images for smartphones, however the iPad 3 is loading these too, despite the max-width property being set to 480px

`@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (max-width: 480px) {`

The iPad 2 however, is fine.

Does anyone know how I can amend the statement so that the iPad 3 ignores it?

Answer (score 1):

Try -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 check this one [Retina iPad Specific CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780189/retina-ipad-specific-css)

Comment: Thanks but I managed to fix it with `@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 480px),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (max-width: 480px)`

Comment: Thats what I suggested :p about pixel ratio 2 is for ipad 3